# function of button onClick gets invoked on first render in React Class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch-api

the code is to fetch data from an API and feel free to state any possible improvement
i made a button to provoke fetch function and input field to read the value from but just for trial purposes i made the value fixed in the code but the onClick function gets invoked on first render without pressing anything ,if someone could elaborate plz.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  
  fetcher = async(userName)=>{
    debugger; // debugger1
    const resp = await fetch(ApiBaseUrl+userName);
    try{
    debugger; // debugger 2
    const data = await resp.json();
    return data;
  }
  catch(error){
    return "error"
  }
}

          
  show = (inputValue) =>
  {
    this.fetcher(inputValue);
    // this.setState({infoHolder: {name:'hossam',age:32}});
    debugger; // debugger 3
  }
    render(){
      debugger; // debugger 4
      return(
        <>
        <label>Please enter the name of the profile you would like to show information for :</label>
        <br></br>
        <input type='text' id = 'UIForProfile'></input>
        <br></br>
        <button onClick={this.show('input')}>Fetch</button>
        </> 
        
      );
  }
}
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

and another question :-
the sequence of debuggers executions is as follows : debugger 4 -> debugger1 -> debugger 3 -> debugger 2.  why did debugger 3 came before debugger 2 'why did the compiler leave the fetcher function and got back to it and why did the function get invoked when i didn't press the button yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the function directly, instead of passing a function to be called when the button is clicked. You can use an arrow function for this like so:

```
<button onClick={() => this.show('input')}>Fetch</button>
```